# Sometimes the program works and sometimes print() command works sometimes it doesn't. What's wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this program. However, weirdly it sometimes prints the correct number, the one I wanted it to print and sometimes it doesn't. By that I mean that the while loop is supposed to continue the loop until the player types/guesses the computers picked number. Thus, when the player enters 4, which the computer has picked (in this example), the while statement is false thus the print command is executed and is supposed to print. Exactly. the pick was 4. However sometimes it prints the number the player has typed however sometimes I guess for example 3 and it prints. Exactly. The pick was 4. I can't figure it out. What is it?
(Hints are highly appreciated )

```
import random

interval_start = 1
interval_end = 5

computer_pick = random.randint(interval_start, interval_end)
player_guess = int(input("I picked a number between %s and %s. Take a guess." % (interval_start, interval_end)))

while player_guess != computer_pick:
    player_guess = int(input("Nah fam. Guess again."))

    print("Exactly. The pick was %s" % computer_pick)
```

Comment: If this is your actual indentation, you want to dedent the last `print`, so it happens after all of the repeated attempts, instead of after getting a new guess on each failed attempt.

Answer (score 1):

If the player guess is correct on the first try, your while loop will not execute.

As your `print` statement is nested within the while loop, it will only be executed if the first guess is incorrect (in which case it will then be executed irrespective of whether the users guess is correct or not.

Dedent your `print` and it should work fine.

Comment: Yes. And then the program is supposed to print. Exactly. The pick was "number guessed on first try". However not always does it do that, even though the correct number is guessed. Instead he prints "Exactly. The pic was 3 even though it was 4 and I guessed on the first try."

Comment: @thebilly: just print outside of a loop

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is simple, let's go through your code block after `while` loop -

```
while player_guess != computer_pick: # Okay so I will run till player_guess is not equal to computer_pick
....player_guess = int(input("Nah fam. Guess again.")) # Four spaces, okay, I am part of this loop

....print("Exactly. The pick was %s" % computer_pick) # Four spaces, okay, I am also part of this loop
```

I have replaced indentation with `.` to make you understand that indentation decides what code will be part of what block. So till the time your above `while` loop runs, the `Exactly` line will also be printed.

We don't want that. What we want is when we exit out of the `while` loop, i.e. when both `player_guess` and `computer_pick` are equal, we print that they picked the right number. So we remove the four indents and bring the `print` statement out of the `while` loop. Like so -

```
while player_guess != computer_pick: # Okay so I will run till player_guess is not equal to computer_pick
....player_guess = int(input("Nah fam. Guess again.")) # Four spaces, okay, I am part of this loop

print("Exactly. The pick was %s" % computer_pick) # Four spaces, okay, I am also part of this loop
```

And now once `while` is done, `Exactly...` is printed

Comment: Will the while clause not actually run until the statement 'player_guess not equal to computer_pick' run until it is false, which is when player_guess = computer_pick? Thank you for the indentation explanation regardless.

Comment: `while` needs a `True` to run. To create infinite loops, we use `while True`. If we take `player_guess = 1` and `computer_pick = 3` and evaluate the statement `player_guess != computer_pick` i.e. `1 is not equal to 3`, it evaluates to be `True`, we get `while True` and loop runs. Similarly if `player_guess = 1` and `computer_pick = 1`, evaluate it `1 is not equal to 1`, evaluates to `False`, we break out of the loop